# DataBinding to a UserControl inside of a UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, user-controls

In my project, I need to DataBind to a UserControl that resides in another UserControl. For the sake of brevity, I created a conceptually similar but very simple project.

Imagine that I am creating a Phone Book application, with two user controls in it, that looks like below.

[image]

The large blue box in the window would be one UserControl, which displays the owner's name (Jane Doe), and each of the yellow boxes within it are also UserControls, which display contacts' names and phone numbers.

I have two classes that I hold related data, as follows:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public Person() { }
}

public class PhoneBook
{
    public string OwnerName { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Person> ContactList { get; set; }
    public PhoneBook() { }
}
```

In my `MainWindow`, I use a ViewModel and bind to the `PhoneBook` UserControl like so:

```
<Window x:Class="UserControlDataBinding.MainWindow"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="350"
        DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource mainViewModelLocator},Path=ViewModelPhoneBook}">
    <Grid>
        <local:UCPhoneBook x:Name="ucPhoneBook" MainPhoneBook="{Binding PhoneBookData}"></local:UCPhoneBook>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

`PhoneBookData` is an instance of `PhoneBook` class on the ViewModel.

My two user controls, and their `DependancyProperties` look like below.

**UCPhoneBook UserControl (the blue box):**

Here I'm using an `ItemsControl` to dynamically bind the `UCPerson` UserControls so I can add as many as I like in runtime.

```
<UserControl x:Class="UserControlDataBinding.UCPhoneBook"
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="450">
    <Canvas x:Name="ucCanvasPhoneBook" Background="White">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <GroupBox Grid.Row="0" Header="Phonebook">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Label Grid.Row="0" Name="lblOwnerName" 
                           Content="{Binding Path=MainPhoneBook.OwnerName}">
                    </Label>
                </Grid>
            </GroupBox>

            <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding PhoneBookData.ContactList}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Person}">
                        <local:UCPerson PersonData="{Binding Person}"></local:UCPerson>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            </ItemsControl>
        </Grid>
    </Canvas>
</UserControl>
```

Its `DependancyProperty`:

```
public partial class UCPhoneBook : UserControl
{
    private static readonly DependencyProperty PhoneBookProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MainPhoneBook", typeof(PhoneBook), typeof(UCPhoneBook), new PropertyMetadata(null));
    public PhoneBook MainPhoneBook
    {
        get { return (PhoneBook)GetValue(PhoneBookProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PhoneBookProperty, value); }
    }

    public UCPhoneBook()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ucCanvasPhoneBook.DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

**UCPerson UserControl (the yellow boxes):**

```
<UserControl x:Class="UserControlDataBinding.UCPerson"
             d:DesignHeight="26" d:DesignWidth="400">
    <Canvas x:Name="ucCanvasPerson" Background="WhiteSmoke">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label Grid.Column="0" Name="lblName" 
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   Content="{Binding Name}"></Label>
            <Label Grid.Column="2" Name="lblPhone" 
                   HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   Content="{Binding Phone}"></Label>
        </Grid>
    </Canvas>
</UserControl>
```

Its `DependancyProperty`:

```
public partial class UCPerson : UserControl
{
    private static readonly DependencyProperty PersonProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("PersonData", typeof(Person), typeof(UCPerson), new PropertyMetadata(null));
    public Person PersonData
    {
        get { return (Person)GetValue(PersonProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PersonProperty, value); }
    }

    public UCPerson()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ucCanvasPerson.DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

When I run this, I can see the Owner's Name at the top of the first UserControl (blue box) just fine. However, it doesn't seem to correctly bind the `UCPerson` user controls within, and I get an empty list like so:

[image]

My guess is that I'm not correctly binding to the `ItemsControl` inside the first UserControl. I'm pretty new to DataBinding and can't seem to figure out what the correct approach is.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Will, I'm a bit confused because that was the article that I was following when I got here. I guess I need to go back and start learning DataBinding from the beginning.

Comment: @Will, thanks! I will check it out. You guys were very helpful.

Comment: @EdPlunkett ah, crap, you're right.  Confusing comments removed to prevent confusion, not out of embarrassment, pinky swears.

Comment: @Will What confusing comments? I saw nothing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can all be greatly simplified.

First, get rid of every `Canvas` in your `UserControl`s. [Canvas isn't just a neutral panel/container control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas(v=vs.110).aspx). The `Canvas`es will cause everything to be superimposed. Only use a `Canvas` when you want to position children arbitrarily, and potentially superimposed. WPF layout usually uses "flow" and relative positioning. The standard layout parents are `StackPanel`, `Grid`, `WrapPanel`, and the occasional `UniformGrid`. You can omit the `ItemsPanelTemplate` for the `ItemsControl`, since the default is already a vertically-oriented `StackPanel`.

Comment: @Will It's the datacontext.

Comment: @EdPlunkett, thanks, that seems to work!

I was following this (http://blog.scottlogic.com/2012/02/06/a-simple-pattern-for-creating-re-useable-usercontrols-in-wpf-silverlight.html) example, and tried to edit here and there. So basically I don't need DependancyProperty for this?

Comment: @Sach That model you chose unfortunately isn't ideal. To be fair it's six years old. The `LayoutRoot.DataContext = this;` thing is much better than the deservedly-reviled `DataContext = this;` (which I think some folks mistakenly thought you were doing), but it's still not regarded as good practice these days.

Comment: I am encountering a different problem now by the way, although probably not related. The `StackPanel` in the 'ItemsPanel' does not stack items, and instead they are on top of each other as seen here: https://i.imgur.com/O6hQzl9.png

Comment: @EdPlunkett thanks for the explanation! Think I will go back to the beginnings and try to understand the concept better, but this is a great starting point.

Comment: @Sach It works very well to provide UC's with their viewmodels as I illustrated above, but there are cases when you might also want to add a dependency property or two, just for purely visual stuff: For example, a parent view might want to pass in some brushes or styles to be applied to part of the UC. So you could write dependnecy properties for that stuff, and inside the UC XAML you would bind like `{Binding BlahStyleProp, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}`. DPs on UCs aren't a Bad Thing -- merely not needful for what you were doing.

Comment: @Sach Looking at that screenshot... not sure what the deal is. Did you try omitting the `ItemsControl.ItemsPanel` element altogether? The default is a vertical stack panel anyhow.

Comment: I removed the ItemsPanel but still the same result. UserControls seem to be stacked up as in the screenshot.

Comment: @Sach I got it! It's the Canvases! Get rid of all the Canvases. They do weird things to layout, it's not just a neutral panel control.

Comment: You're right! I used a Canvas so I have more control over Background Color etc, but I'm sure I can achieve the same result without one. Thanks again!